# Is rewrite in .htaccess visible to users?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using the following Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /secretpage.php [L]
```

Is there anyway someone can know that the page being served now is `/secretpage.php` on the server?
I am not asking if someone can get to this page alone by typing it in the URL line, but rather if someone can know about the rewrite that was made on the server side.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you make that rewrite an external redirect, the rewrite is only done internally. An external redirect happens either explicitly by using the *R* flag or implicitly when an absolute URL is used as substitution (although there are some further restrictions).

But the substition is still accessible when requesting it directly. So your rule will only add a way to access *secretpage.php* and it is then accessible by both `/page.html` and `/secretpage.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible as it's the server which perform rewriting. Anyway request's headers don't let see anything.